# Нужны ли здесь знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

(Очевидные знаки на месте.)

Трудиться над общим делом, чтобы не престала память родителей наших и наша и свеча бы не угасла.

Comment: Всем — спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

***Трудиться над общим делом, чтобы не престала память родителей наших и наша и свеча бы не угасла.***

Я бы не ставил. Хотя причины сомневаться мне понятны. Здесь имеет место нарушение классической грамматики, хотя не уверен, что сейчас это по-прежнему считается ошибкой). Вопрос по поводу "бы" во второй части.

Союза **"чтобы... и... бы"** грамматика раньше не знала. Не очевидно, есть ли он и сейчас. И можно ли переносить правила "общей части", применяемое в отношении союза "И", на неочевидный союз "чтобы... и ... бы" совершенно не ясно.

Раньше, строго по грамматике, фраза писалась одним из следующих способов.

*Трудиться над общим делом, чтобы не престала память родителей наших и наша и чтобы свеча не угасла.*

или

*Трудиться над общим делом, чтобы не престала память родителей наших и наша и свеча не угасла.*

(Последний вариант уже более поздний).

В обоих случаях запятая не нужна по правилу общей части, но здесь очевидный, ничем не замутненный союз "И" между двумя придаточными с общей главной частью.

ну будем считать, что "по аналогии" можно перенести и на исходное.

Answer (score 1):

(1)Трудиться над общим делом, (2)чтобы не престала память родителей наших и наша (память) и (3)свеча бы не угасла.

Дополнительных запятых не нужно. Это СПП с однородными придаточными цели, связанных одиночным союзом И, запятая между ними не ставится.

Первый союз И связывает однородные подлежащие "не престала **память** родителей наших и наша (**память**)", предложение неполное, второе подлежащее пропущено. Запятая также н нужна (одиночный союз И).

Comment: «Второе подлежащее пропущено».Так, может быть, поставить тире по месту пропуска: память родителей наших и — наша?

Comment: Нет, тире не нужно, паузы  нет, да к тому же пропущенное подлежащее "память"  подразумевается после слова "наша", а не перед ним. Здесь немного архаичный стиль грамматики,  в современном языке такие конструкции встречаются не часто.

Answer (score 1):

**Знаки поставлены верно**, но второе придаточное **формально неоднородно** с первым, хотя однородность автором предполагается. Так что построено предложение **неверно**: ***бы*** надо заменить на ***чтобы***. Авторский вариант допустим разве что в разговорном стиле.

Простите, я неправильно прочитала слово "престала". Убираю попутное замечание.

Comment: «А пишу вам се слово того для, чтобы не перестала память родителей наших и наша и свеча бы не погасла». Великий князь Семен Иванович Гордый (1317 — 1353).

Comment: Так это совсем другое дело! В таком виде предложение с учётом времени высказывания выглядит даже красиво. Никакого смешения французского с нижегородским.